# Running my script at real hosting

Tags: php

My script is working fine on localhost but it is not working on my domain.

```
<?php

    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', true);

    $needle = $_POST['utext'];
    $file = $_POST['ufile'];
    $new = file($file);
    $new = array('trim', $new);
    echo '#entries: ', count($new), "\n";
    $found = array(); $notfound=array();

    foreach ( $new as $check ) {
        echo "<table border='1'><tr>";
        echo '<td>processing = ', $check.'</td>';
        $a = file_get_contents($check);

        if (strpos($a,$needle)) {
            echo "<td><font color='green'> found\n</font></td>";
            $found[] = $check;
        }
        else {
            echo "<td><font color='red' face='bold'> not found\n</font></td>";
            $notfound[] = $check;
        }
    }

    echo '<tr><td>#Matches: ', count($found), "</td></tr>";
    echo "<br />";
    echo '#No-Matches: ', count($notfound), "\n";
    echo "<br />";
    echo "</tr></table>";

?>
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my script or any other problem?

Addition:

I am receiving this error message

> Warning: file(Your-Backlinks.txt) [function.file]: failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/husdemo/public_html/backlink.php on line 27 Warning:
>   file_get_contents(trim) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/husdemo/public_html/backlink.php on line 35

Comment: Maybe php version in your local and remote server is different

Comment: maybe php.ini configurations aren't same

Comment: If any error messages are being show it would really help us if you add them to your question

Comment: Warning: file(Your-Backlinks.txt) [function.file]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/husdemo/public_html/backlink.php on line 27
Warning: file_get_contents(trim) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/husdemo/public_html/backlink.php on line 35

Comment: the file is uploaded by user.

Comment: No sanitation/validation on the file name is extremely dangerous

Comment: The folder has the correct permissions to upload to?

Answer (score 2):

Upload **Your-Backlinks.txt** to server

Comment: allow_url_fopen is already on

Comment: I have uploaded it but this time also the same result

Comment: Did you get the same error message?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the short-tag `<?` rather than the full `<?php` tag? If so, change it to full tags, your host might very well have short-tags disabled.